# Should clash of clans and/or other games be valid?

Tags: discussion, ios

I lately seen a lot of clash of clans and other games topics here. Should they be related to our topic of apple? I see the games as universal across all platforms (like android) and should not be related purely to apple and they should use another site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [help center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Ask Different is for users of Apple products. If you have a question about ...
>
> - [...]
> - third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products.
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!

so problems related to software running on Apple hardware are on-topic. Also a lot of these questions are related to the interaction between the game and Game Center which clearly is an Apple-related issues.

OTOH questions purely focusing on in-game issues are off-topic (but I haven't seen many of these here).